How to install xorg-x11-apps-7.7-21.el8.x86_64.rpm LOCALLY on CENTOS 8?
I am trying to get "xeyes" installed and working on a "CentOS 8 (8.5.2111)" machine.
I was previously able to download "xorg-x11-apps-7.7-21.el8.x86_64.rpm" and install it on a CENTOS Stream 9 machine using:
dnf localinstall ./xorg-x11-apps-7.7-21.el8.x86_64.rpm

But when I try running the same command line on CENTOS 8 I get:
[root@localhost apps]# dnf localinstall ./xorg-x11-apps-7.7-21.el8.x86_64
CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                        0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:01
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'appstream':
  - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock [Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org]

I think that that "mirrorlist.centos.org" no longer exists.
I don't quite understand why the command works on CENTOS 9, but doesn't work on CENTOS 8?
Does anyone know if there is a way to get that RPM installed on my CENTOS 8 machine?
Thanks,
Jim
EDIT: Answering my own question, I was able to install the RPM using "rpm":
rpm -ivh --nodeps xorg-x11-apps-7.7-21.el8.x86_64


Answering my own question, I was able to install the RPM using "rpm":
rpm -ivh --nodeps xorg-x11-apps-7.7-21.el8.x86_64
